# Using PdfStamper How I can save the merged PDF under a folder using itext then read it

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to save my merged PDF on my hard disk then load it as final PDF

below is my code (with Safri on IPAD the PDF alwasy is empty)

```
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(folder + fileName);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper( reader, out, '\0', true );
            AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
            String fdfContent = (String) request.getAttribute("fdfContent");
            FdfReader fdfReader = new FdfReader(fdfContent.getBytes());
            fields.setFields(fdfReader);
            out.flush();
            stamper.close();
            reader.close();
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need to write the file to a disk?  You can do all operations on the PDF in memory and then write the final output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper( reader, out, '\0', false );
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```